# Multiple small image stitching (orthomosaic, map2d)

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, accord.net

I have multiple small images of world map (taken from drone on every 1 sec, so new image overlaps previous one).

If I put them on map, the output looks like
[image]

I am looking for some fast library that would be able to stitch images so I can show the map.
I already tryed Emgu, Accord, OpenCvSharp... but I am stuck, because some of them are not able to properly stitch images since they are small, some of them are to slow and some are loosing image quality by every new stitching.

What is the correct method to create orthomosaic?

Currently I am stitching new image to previous one (which is already stitched with previous one), I thought this will be faster and since I do not have all images at once I thought its the correct way, but as I already told I am loosing images quality, also if I try to stitch all current images at once it takes to much time.

Any suggestions and pointing will be great.

Here is example data
[image data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/150585606282fdc4400e8402291c4f7320200714061607/975d53d056ad2589fab840e0ac162f0d20200714061636/cff5b3)

Currently With Accord.Net and bellow code (stitching new one to previous already stitched) after 4 images there become a problem

```
//1
HarrisCornersDetector harris = new HarrisCornersDetector(0.04f, 1000f);
harrisPoints1 = harris.ProcessImage(img1).ToArray();
harrisPoints2 = harris.ProcessImage(img2).ToArray();
//2
CorrelationMatching matcher = new CorrelationMatching(9, img1, img2);
IntPoint[][] matches = matcher.Match(harrisPoints1, harrisPoints2);

// Get the two sets of points
correlationPoints1 = matches[0];
correlationPoints2 = matches[1];
//3
RansacHomographyEstimator ransac = new RansacHomographyEstimator(0.001, 0.99);
homography = ransac.Estimate(correlationPoints1, correlationPoints2);
//4 
Blend blend = new Blend(homography, img1);
Bitmap output = blend.Apply(img2);

output.MakeTransparent();
output.Save(locationName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
output.Dispose();
```

[image]

Comment: If it were possible I would recommend using the positional data of your drone, whether through GPS or dead reckoning to at least group you images into neighborhoods prior to stitching. Reconstruct images within a region, then neighboring regions to one another. This approach will reduce the computational requirement when compared to "stitching all current images at once" and will allow for parallelization.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I know latitude/longitude of all 4 corners of each image. How can I use this for speed up?
Can you give me more info about this other metods prior to stitching?

Comment: That makes the job a lot easier. It's hard to provide you with an answer without sample data/images and the code you've tried previously, however you should first group subsets of images by proximity prior to stitching. Depending on the density, you also have the luxury of knowing which edges of which images should stitch/overlay. Create subsets using the GPS data, stitch those images, stitch the results. This will allow you to parallel process and improve performance.

Comment: For example, if you have 100 images, create 10 groups of 10, stitch them in parallel. Then stitch pairs of images in parallel to produce 5 images. Stitch the 5 images in series and you're finished. Optimizing the group size versus iterations can take some work, however again it's hard to advise without seeing samples.

Comment: What is the correct aproach... lets say that I take new image every 1 second, is it smart to merge/stitch this to previous already stitched image or is smart to have all images in buffer and then make the merge/stitch?
I will upload the data tomorow.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I added example data in origingal message.

Comment: Okay, leave this with me. If I find some time I'll try and work on a solution.

Comment: An update: https://imgur.com/YDPvkaV This is the plotted image bounds from the GPS data. The locations aren't so accurate to combine the images directly from these transforms, but they can help to group neighboring images and correct for perspective. I'll keep working as I find time.

Comment: Yes I already know that... I will put original image in original message.

Comment: You'll find it easier to get answer from this platform if invest time and detail in the initial question and act courteously with people making effort to help you. "Thank you, I'd managed that", rather than "Yes I already know that", for example. Simply put, you need to batch the stitching process  so that it can be parallelized for performance.

Comment: Other than that, I believe what is causing you initial attempts to fail is the cross target within the images. They will cause false correlations between the images as they'll be consider common points. This will be especially a problem if you are using Harris as the only "corners" in the image are those of the target. Consider SURF to extract common points, Harris is not appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I am already working on removing target from video stream. I am also checking if georeferenc points are refreshed fast enaff as video stream (I think the diference bettwen images should be smaller on map).
I am still waiting if someone will tell me what is the best aproach... stiching to previous or all at once.

Comment: Regarding the georeference points; they provide about the level of accuracy I would expect actually. I'm speculating that you're GPS is accurate to maybe  +/- 1 or 2m? That's approximately +/- 15 pixels in your images judging by the cars. The other thing to note, which is cool, is that the gps corner locations you are given do not form a rectangle, they are projected points, presumably projected to a plane at ground level given the altitude of the drone. Note their shape in the image I provided, they include the perspective of the gimbal. This gets pretty wide in the turns.  1/2

Comment: For the "best approach", I'll try and explain my recommendation again: Take a subset of images you know to be overlapping (due to the geolocations), say for example the first 5. Stitch them "all at once". At the same time, in parallel, stitch other groups of 5 e.g. images 6-10. In this way, you can take 100 images, to 20 images, then perhaps to 5 images, and finally to 1. The trick will be optimizing this 100-20-5-1 pattern given the weight of the algorithm and power of your hardware etc e.g. perhaps 100-10-1 will perform better. Does that make sense? 2/2

Comment: Ignore this if it's not helpful but it may be a better explanation of the parallelization principles: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/parallel_algorithm/parallel_algorithm_introduction.htm#:~:text=An%20algorithm%20is%20a%20sequence,to%20produce%20the%20final%20result. And this video for an intro to async programming in C#: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2moh18sh5p4

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood how to know where to put new stitched image, how to know image georeference when image is stitched?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood since I am using GMap tiles I sorted images depend on in which tile it goes, https://imgur.com/a/YeLTiCv so in tile like 70617x46719 with zoom 17 I now have 10-20 images. I made all images 256x256, is this good for stitching, that all are the same size? Some images are now almost empty, how to stitch them in this case?

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood did you had any time to try the stitching? Can share some code?

Answer (score 0):

The basic principles of stitching images together are pretty straightforward, but there are endless details that affect the final quality.

Open Drone Map is worth taking a look at.

I have developed a pure-python (+ opencv) image stitching tool chain to support my university research projects.  It is open-source (MIT license.)  My work is intentionally designed as a 'guts out' system.  Here is the github link:

https://github.com/UASLab/ImageAnalysis

I would love to answer further specific questions about my work and if I can answer broader questions (up to the limit of my experience) I am happy to do that too.

(Screen shots from my toolkit available at the above link ... I don't have enough reputations yet in order to post images.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for getting involved. Just a tip early on as the community can be quite pedantic: Try to keep discussion, or generalities in the comments. Although helpful, you answer in not an "answer". Perhaps consider modifying to show a worked example using the suggested library? Although, OP has tagged this question C#, so python example can only be helpful in the pseudo sense.

Comment: Can you point me to specific file where code uses geocordinates for stitching?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm new to the culture here.  The system lets me post an 'answer' but doesn't let me post a comment to the original question because I don't have enough points yet. :-(  I can apparently comment to my own post, so that's ok.

Comment: Martin: it is not that simple.  My system uses direct georefernencing to get an initial guess for all the feature locations, then throws that into a big optimizer to chew on and fit everything together "perfectly."  The math is just projecting a pixel out into camera 3d coordinates, transforming that to world 3d coordinates (based on camera orientation/location.)  And then somehow deciding where the vector intersects the ground (and what ground elevation even is.)  I had good luck triangulating pairs of images to correct for major heading error and estimating ground surface.

Comment: Also, sorry, all my work is in python.  I'm not a C# person.  Variety is good though, and we are all most productive in the environments we are most comfortable and like, so it's all good.  Math is still math.  Logic is still logic.  Doesn't matter how we express it.  (hehe, mostly)